# Linking boost libraries C::B Ubuntu

Tags: boost, ubuntu, codeblocks

I am trying to link the libraries from boost to C::B. I have built the files but all I see in all the folders are .hpp files. Are there not supposed to be .lib files?

Going through build options, I gave search directories. I am now trying to do the linker settings. What do I put here. It will only take .lib and other files like that. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you followed the [Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) from the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Boost libraries? The *vast* majority of Boost libraries are header-only. You only need to include the header file to use them. The only Boost libraries that have actual library files are:

- Date_Time
- Filesystem
- Graph
- iostreams
- Math
- Program Options
- Random
- Regex
- Serialization
- Signals
- System
- Thread
- Wave

Also, you're working with GCC. Library files end in ".a", not ".lib" as with Visual Studio.